# Заполнение списка из таблицы

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь в Ruby сделать выпадающий список, который заполняется из таблице.
Примерный механизм понятен и у меня получается его заполнять, но только одним элементом.
Вот как это делаю:

```
@tableall = Table.first // или last // выборка из таблице
SELECT_TYPE = [@tableall.text] // позволяет заполнить мне список одним элементом
```

Но как мне вывести весь столбец "text", я не пойму.
Если вести выборку методом "all", то будет ошибка - полагаю в таком случае дынные выгружаются в не приемлемом формате для "SELECT_TYPE".
Но как тогда выводить данные?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте это: http://rusrails.ru/rails-form-helpers

Пункт: "3. Легкое создание списков выбора"

И это: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Советую использовать помощник collection_select. Гугл поможет, будут вопросы -- обращайтесь.

SELECT_TYPE у вас является константой. Это намеренно?

Answer (score 2):

А кто у вас читает `SELECT_TYPE`? Почему `SELECT_TYPE` у вас заглавными буквами? Заглавными буквами пишутся константы.
Нужно делать:

```
@tableall = Table.all
...
render ваша_вьюха
```

Вьюха.erb:

```
<% @tableall.each do |table| %>
  <%= table.text %>
<% end %>
```

Обратите внимание, где берётся свойство `text`.